# ObjectMapper - How to send null value in JSON

Tags: java, json, null, objectmapper

According to third party API spec, I need to send null value in JSON using `ObjectMapper` if no value exists,

Expected results : `"optional": null`

If optional value exists, then send `"optional": "value"`

I didn't find such option in [Jackson – Working with Maps and nulls](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-map-null-values-or-null-key)

Code:

```
requestVO = new RequestVO(optional);
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String requestString = mapper.writeValueAsString(requestVO);
```

Class:

```
public class RequestVO {
   String optional;
   public RequestVO(String optional) {
      this.optional = optional;
   }

public String getOptional() {
    return optional;
}

public void setOptional(String optional) {
    this.optional= optional;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.USE_DEFAULTS)` annotation to your class.

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.USE_DEFAULTS)
class RequestVO {
    String optional;

    public RequestVO(String optional) {
        this.optional = optional;
    }

    public String getOptional() {
        return optional;
    }

    public void setOptional(String optional) {
        this.optional = optional;
    }
}
```

Example :

```
RequestVO requestVO = new RequestVO(null);

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
try {
    String requestString = mapper.writeValueAsString(requestVO);
    System.out.println(requestString);
} catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Output :

```
{"optional":null}
```

With value:

```
RequestVO requestVO = new RequestVO("test");

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
try {
    String requestString = mapper.writeValueAsString(requestVO);
    System.out.println(requestString);
} catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Output:

```
{"optional":"test"}
```

You can use `@JsonInclude` annotation on even properties. So, this way you can either serialize as null or ignore some of the properties while serializing.

Comment: @user7294900 I updated the answer. It gives you an option to serializing some null properties and ignoring some other properties.

Answer (score 3):

You can configure your ObjectMapper this way:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
```

If no value is present on the JSON request your processed will have a `null` as you expected.

You can even configure a `Spring` bean for the `ObjectMapper` if you need.

**EDIT:**

I misunderstood the question, he was interested  on the JSON response and not on the object parsed. **The correct property is this case is `JsonInclude.Include.USE_DEFAULTS`**.

Apologies for the confusion.

Comment: You mean `Include.NON_NULL`? it removes optional parameter

Comment: Yes, in this case it will only process the value if is present, and will default to `null` otherwise. But reading again I think I misunderstood the question. You expect that the JSON response always had the field correct? Is not about processing the request.

Comment: If you use this setting, it does not serialize as OP's ask. It does not serialize null values. Take a look at serialized string, it contains nothing when you pass Include.NON_NULL.

Comment: You are right @EmreSavcı I misunderstood the objective and already edited the question to reflect this and apologize for my confusion.